# Eigen Values and Nature of Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let J be a 3x3 matrix all of whose entries are 1.Then (i)0 and 3 are the only eigen value of J 
(ii)J is positive semi definite. (iii)J is diagonalizable (iv)J is positive definite.

Here,

J is positive semi definite iff all its eigenvalues are nonnegetive.

J is positive definite iff all its eigenvalues are positive.

J is diagonalizable iff its minimal polynomial can be expressed as a product of disjoint linear factors over R.

Option (i),(ii)and(iii) are correct.Am i right?

Comment: Can you at least find on your own whether $J$ is invertible?

Comment: singular matrix. Not invertible.

Comment: OK. So 0 is an eigenvalue, right? What does the rank-nullity theorem tell you now?

Comment: I can understand the nature of the matrix here.It is also diagonalizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

- $J$ is positive semi definite iff all its eigenvalues are nonnegetive.
- $J$ is positive definite iff all its eigenvalues are positive.
- $J$ is diagonalizable iff its minimal polynomial can be expressed as a product of disjoint linear factors over $\mathbb R.$